# Kannel Sms Count

Tags: open-source, sms, kannel

I am using kannel. I have a problem when I send message longer than 160 char. Kannel splits it into 2 or more messages. Only on the first one the registered delivery flag is set. That means that kannel asks for DLR's only on the first part.

can I be sure that all parts has been delivered ? 
Can I set  registered delivery flag for all parts of message ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear from the question but (as of Kannel 1.5.0):

1. If you have a problem with long messages being split into separate SMS messages, you should set the *concatenation* parameter to *true* in sendsms configuration. That way Kannel will construct a proper multipart message;
2. Re: the second part about DLRs - no, unfortunately it seems that Kannel intentionally sets the *registered_delivery* flag for the first part/message only. In theory it should take into account DLRs for all parts, however, in practice such issues are very rare (depends on your SMSCs, though.) I assume Kannel authors decided the performance gains were significant enough to do so.

Comment: thanks for your response.. actually ..when I send msg longer than 160 character I get response from kannel only one time....Is there any possibility to get response more than 1 time if the length of msg crossed 160 char. I am not counting characters from my side. If it is possible to get response from kannel then it will be good for my project

Comment: See the second point in my answer - basically, Kannel ignores the reports on the second, third, etc. part of the message - however, cases where you should be worried about such situations are so rare that, if it's an issue for you, either your SMSC is terrible, or you've grown past using Kannel which  doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: although it is very old post, but did u find any solution? In my case I get the DLR on first segment delivery and all the segments are not being delivered to handset and in result fake DLR complain

Answer (score 1):

Most of smsc venders give delivery flag only if full part of message is delivered in hand set

Answer (score 0):

Any mobile service provider allows you to send only 160 one time, that's why its spiting into two parts.
Are you using sqlbox for sending messages? Sometimes it may help. I am not so sure about it yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this directive on smsc group

[image]

Refer here http://kannel.org/download/1.5.0/userguide-1.5.0/userguide.html#AEN1198